# Regexp using Netbeans:

Tags: regex, netbeans, replace

I would like to make the following find and replace:

```
// input
'key1': 1 
'key2': 2 

// output
key1: 1 
key2: 2
```

the find should be like this pattern `'\w{1,}':`
what about the replace with pattern?

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: @Raze2dust it doesnt matter the language, the OP wants to use the find/replace feature in netbeans...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should remove the quotes from the keys:

Find: `'(.+)':`

Replace: `$1`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The Replace button seems to be disabled when I try that and `$1` is in **red**

Comment: Weird. I tried it and it worked fine for me. I'm on 7.1. Was anything found in the find?

Comment: yea, I am testing it in one of my files on Netbeans `7.0.1`

Comment: Does anything get found when you use Previous and Next? Do you have any text selected?

Comment: I don't have a previous and next. this is what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6f779.png

Comment: Ah. 7.1 has a different dialog. Have you tried the regexp I provided? Yours still doesn't provide a capture group which is needed to replace.

Comment: Thanks you should just correct your answer: `'(.+)':` instead of `'(.+)'`

Comment: Added the colon. Your post didn't have it which is why I didn't put it in there. Glad you got it working.